# TYPE ERROR !!! TypeError: Cannot read property 'cityName' of undefined. WHERE AM I GOING WRONG?

Tags: node.js

THIS IS THE HTML. My text input is what i call in my js file.

```
  <input type="text" name="cityName" id="cityInput">
  <button type="submit">GO</button>
```

THIS IS MY JS FILE. i cannot figure out what part is off!

```
const express = require("express");


const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const https = require("https");


const app = express();


app.get("/" , function(req , res){


res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");



});

app.post("/" , function(req , res){
const query = req.body.cityName;
const unit = "metric";


const url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q= " + query + "&appid=c4a24f0d347df1c5d36cf4ffdaad1d7" + unit+ "";


https.get(url , function(response){

response.on("data" , function(data){

  const weatherData = JSON.parse(data);

  const temp = weatherData.main.temp;

  const weatherDescription = weatherData.weather[0].description;

res.write("The tempereature in " + query + " is" + temp + " degree Celsius.");

  res.send();
```

Avoid:

jne. eeuneuheiubebej
jiehnvue
buvbuebvievnr 
ivbjv j jnkfjifirvv

Comment: Please share the logic for how you are sending the post request.

Comment: this is pretty much the code. i was missing -- app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

i do however have a new error that says --- TypeError: Cannot read property 'temp' of undefined .

Comment: @Ro Try attaching a debugger and check what the value of `weatherData` or `data` is. Alternatively, simply use a `console.log`. You will likely find that `weatherData` does not contain a property named `main`, which then leads to the newly seen exception when trying to access `weatherData.main.temp`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but likely what you need is to add the `bodyParser` as a middleware. If you are using JSON for the body of the request, it should simply be adding the following before registering any of your routes:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

The error you are getting is trying to tell you that `req.body` is undefined. This is because the `req.body` is not populated automatically. Adding the bodyParser middleware will ensure that it gets populated. Not that if you are using some other content type for the request body, you will need another parser. E.g. for form data you'll need;

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! that hepls! :)  that was it! great shot!